# Google_drive_api image-id

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Good afternoon. I have created an algorithm to read all files in a google drive folder. But for some reason it returns the wrong image ids (i.e.not the ones of the actual link. Any ideas why this is happenning?

```py
def retrieve_all_files(service):
      """Retrieve a list of File resources.
    
      Args:
        service: Drive API service instance.
      Returns:
        List of File resources.
      """
      result = []
      page_token = None
      while True:
        try:
          param = {}
          if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
    
          folder_id = '11yxEiK2WgoRXJ6rEcWgRf0od5Y5BBV6L'
          query = f"parents = '{folder_id}'"
          files = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
          result.extend(files['items'])
          page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
    
    
          if not page_token:
            break
        except errors.HttpError as error:
          print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
          break
      return result
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
    credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    
    service = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
    images = retrieve_all_files(service)
```

Comment: Could you add an example of expected output?

Comment: Your `result` variable will contain files. Where are you even asking for "image ids"?